# Can i use returning promise in socket.io "socket.on(eventName, callback)"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, promise

Can i use returning promise in socket.io "socket.on"? Like the following code.

```
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
      return News.findOne({id: data.id})
        .then((news) => {
          socket.emit('event', data.body);
          return news;
        })
    });
```

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you can, it just doesn't do anything. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: in other words, return inside `.on` callback isn't returned anywhere

Comment: I want to make chat room application with socket.io. So, i tried to record chat message to mongodb database when the server get message event @robertklep

Comment: @ashnamuh you don't need `socket.io` to support promises for that.

Comment: But i have no idea how to make it. What is the thing that i need? I just want to record chat message to my mongoDB

Answer (score 1):

In your socket.io server side part of your code you could use the node module 'node-mongodb-native' which in its [documentation section](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/crud/) shows you how to save something to your mongoDB instance like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  // Insert a single document
  db.collection('inserts').insertOne({a:1}, function(err, r) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);

    // Insert multiple documents
    db.collection('inserts').insertMany([{a:2}, {a:3}], function(err, r) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      assert.equal(2, r.insertedCount);

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```